# Can I change the storage location for individual replicated VMs in Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have 2 Windows servers (2016)

- one replicates VMs to the other.
- On the replication server, I have two drives (C & D).

Is it possible to change the location of individual VMs that are replicated to the replication server? For example, have some go to the C drive and others to the D drive? This does not seem to be possible as I can only configure the location of the replicated VMs in Hyper-V Manager.

If it is not possible to configure in Hyper-V, what would be the recommendation/options (if any) to be able to use both drives as storage options for the replicated VMs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible. You create replica to a default location and then move VM to a different location on the destination host. More information: https://virtualizationreview.com/Blogs/Virtual-Insider/2013/09/7-Steps-Hyper-V-Replicas.aspx

Check the [this](https://www.hyper-v.io/hyper-v-replica/) article to find some tips about working with Hyper-V Replica.

Comment: thanks for that, the article was very helpful and I'll try this out and report back. Appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Comment: Hope this will help. Good luck.